# How to create a custom button and add it programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, styles

I need to create a customized button and add it programmatically.
I already found a few examples I tried them out, but when I add it to my Activity I cannot see anything.

This is my Code:

Activity:

```
        Button btn = new Button(Einstellungen.this, null, R.attr.CustomButton);
```

in attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
<attr name="CustomButton" format="reference"/>
```

In styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="CustomButton">@style/someStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="someStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">2px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000</item>
</style>
```

When I start my app there is no Button.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do accept the answers that help you reach the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should also define button's layout params (if not defined in styles) and put the button into the activity's layout. Suppose you have `LinearLayout` with an id `activity_layout`, then it could be something like this:

```java
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_layout);
Button button = new Button(Einstellungen.this, null, R.attr.CustomButton);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
layout.addView(button);
```

Note you should use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` that is in your defined style. From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT):

> `fill_parent` means that the view wants to be as big as its parent, minus the parent's padding, if any. This value is deprecated from API Level 8 and onwards and replaced by `match_parent`.

Comment: I tried it out but there is still nothing to sett in my Activity :(

Comment: Try to remove the style and define button just with `Button button = new Button(this);`. Also - you should run this code in `OnCreate()` method of your activity.

Comment: Ok so Button button = new Button(this); is working. Obviously there is a mistake from my side within the style.xml?

Comment: Yes it seems like that. Try to set layout width and height to 'wrap_content' or 'match_parent'

Comment: Nothing's changed :/

Comment: @peter12395 I recommend you to use xml for defining your button and not to use styles until you have more buttons with the same style and you can actually reuse it. If my answer was helpful to you please upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this after declaring the button:

```
 layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_of_your_xml);
 btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.addView(buyButton);
```

If your xml has a different layout, you can even initialize and assign that instead of LinearLayout

Comment: I tried it out but there is still nothing to sett in my Activity :(

Comment: Please post your java file along with xml, so that we can understand it further